# I won't be changing too/either

Tags: negative-polarity-items

A song called "Same Old Love" by Selena Gomez has [these lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/same-old-love-lyrics-selena-gomez.html):

> Take away your things and go
>
> You can't take back what you said, I know
>
> I've heard it all before, at least a million times
>
> I'm not one to forget, you know
>
> I don't believe, I don't believe it
>
> You left in peace, left me in pieces
>
> Too hard to breathe, I'm on my knees
>
> Right now, 'ow
>
> I'm so sick of that same old love, that shit, it tears me up
>
> ...
>
> I'm not spending any time, wasting tonight on you
>
> I know, I've heard it all
>
> So don't you try and change your mind
>
> Cause I won't be changing **too**, you know
>
> ...

In the last line, is it natural to use **too** as in the lyrics or is it more natural to use **either** instead here?

Comment: I think the meaning is *Don't try and change your mind. Because (if you do) I won't be changing too*.

Comment: @Araucaria I, for one, think that she doesn't want him to bother to change his mind, because she won't be changing her mind anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Logically "I won't be changing either" suggests that I will not change my mind, whether or not you change yours

while "I won't be changing too" may suggest that I will not change my mind if you change yours

In the context, this makes little difference in substantive meaning. Whichever fits the rhythm of the poem is better

Comment: If I understand the lyrics correctly, I think that she assumes that he's trying to change his mind. That's why she said, "don't you try and change your mind". If so, you're saying that 'too' is more correct as in the original lyrics, right?

Comment: Both suggest she thinks there are no circumstances in which they both change their minds.  They differ in whether it is possible that she might change her mind while he does not, but that is not relevant to the context of the song